# controlling headphones jack

Tags: audio, sound-card, speakers, headphones

I have problem with my laptop which is it doest recognize my headphones whenever i plug them in , but sound as in music or games go through both speakers and headphones at the same time .
is there any program to stop the speakers manually without stopping the headphone ? and does anyone have a solution for this problem in the first place ?
I am using HP Pavilion Sleekbook 15 , windows 8 pro 64-bit .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Don't connect your headphones now.

Click the speaker icon in the task bar. and click the Speakers icon on top of the volume slider.

Now the Speaker Properties window appears on the screen. 
You'll see Device usage there which is set to "Use this device(enable)"
Change that to "Don't use this device(disable)"
Then click OK

If you doesn't have a headphone connected you will see a 'x' on the speaker icon in the task bar.Connect your headphones.Now Click that icon.

Speaker troubleshooter appears. It will automatically identifies the speakers otherwise you will have to follow the on-screen instructions .

Hope this method help.

Comment: I tried what u said but in sound >playback  there is only (speakers an headphones ) enabled so when i disable it both of them will turn off , I think it is a problem in the 3.5 mm jack in my laptop so that's why I was searching for the program . and thank u btw .